# Play Framework GUID

Tags: configuration, playframework

I have created a play application. When i am running the application i'm getting this error both in dev and prod

```
07:59:58,445 INFO  ~ Precompiling ...
08:00:08,884 ERROR ~ Unable to set localhost. This prevents creation of a GUID. Cause was: sys3: sys3: Name or service not known
java.net.UnknownHostException: sys3: sys3: Name or service not known
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1438)
    at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.<clinit>(Cache.java:155)
    at net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationHelper.createCache(ConfigurationHelper.java:298)
    at net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationHelper.createDefaultCache(ConfigurationHelper.java:214)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.configure(CacheManager.java:552)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.init(CacheManager.java:323)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.<init>(CacheManager.java:279)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.create(CacheManager.java:641)
    at play.cache.EhCacheImpl.<init>(EhCacheImpl.java:31)
    at play.cache.EhCacheImpl.newInstance(EhCacheImpl.java:41)
    at play.cache.Cache.init(Cache.java:241)
    at play.Play.start(Play.java:511)
    at play.Play.init(Play.java:300)
    at play.server.Server.main(Server.java:158)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: sys3: Name or service not known
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:866)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1258)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1434)
    ... 13 more
```

I don't know what is this, what this will do. How to solve this issue. Pl help me.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

java is unable to resolve mynap3 as localhost, so you'll have to add the line

```
127.0.0.1 localhost mynap3
```

to your /etc/hosts file

you can do this by executing

```
sudo bash
echo "127.0.0.1 localhost mynap3" >> /etc/hosts
```