# Why does java.net.UnknownHostException require changes to the hosts file?

Tags: java, playframework

In regards to this question [Play Framework GUID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8562881/play-framework-guid) why do I have to change my hosts file? I was having a similar issue while running a test in fedora which returned the following error

```
[error] (*:testListeners) java.net.UnknownHostException: fedora: fedora: Name 
or service not known
```

I added the line

```
127.0.0.1 localhost fedora
```

to my /etc/hosts file, which fixed this, but why should this have to be done in the first place?

Comment: without that in your host file, what happens if you ping fedora?

Comment: But why does it need the host fedora? That does not follow the philosophy of write once run everywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Play server loads EhCache. When EhCache is loaded (specifically `net.sf.ehcache.Cache`) it attempts to determine the address for localhost which is used in a process to create GUIDs identifying the cache instances created. EhCache does this by calling `InetAddress.getLocalHost()`. This method searches your host file for an entry matching the hostname set for the local machine, if it doesn't find one it throws an `UnknownHostException`.

The fix, as demonstrated in an answer to the question you linked, is to set a host entry for the local hostname.

Comment: It's a bit more tricky than that for folks on a DHCP network where our hostnames aren't fixed.  For me, this was working ten minutes ago, now, it's not.  I'm guessing my lease renewed and I got a new host name or something.