# play testing fails (playframework 2.2.2)

Tags: java, testing, junit, playframework, playframework-2.0

Just getting used to the Play Framework and setting up a new Web Application.

I wanted to do some Model Unit Tests but when I run `play test` I get the following error message:

```
[Opinions] $ test
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last *:testListeners for the full output.
[error] (*:testListeners) java.net.UnknownHostException: linux-hkem.site: linux-hkem.site: Der Name oder der Dienst ist nicht bekannt
[error] Total time: 10 s, completed 12.04.2014 21:42:35
```

`Der Name oder der Dienst ist nicht bekannt` is german and means:

`The name or the service is not recognized`

`linux-hkem` is my PC name. This seems not to be a code error, but rather a configuration error. Anyone could help me out fixing this?

Heres the full stack trace:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: linux-hkem.site: linux-hkem.site: Der Name oder der Dienst ist nicht bekannt
        at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1473)
        at eu.henkelmann.sbt.JUnitXmlTestsListener.<init>(JUnitXmlTestListener.scala:25)
        at play.Settings$$anonfun$defaultSettings$17.apply(PlaySettings.scala:94)
        at play.Settings$$anonfun$defaultSettings$17.apply(PlaySettings.scala:94)
        at scala.Function2$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function2.scala:54)
        at scala.Function2$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function2.scala:53)
        at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
        at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
        at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
        at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
        at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
        at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
        at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: linux-hkem.site: Der Name oder der Dienst ist nicht bekannt
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
        at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:901)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1293)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1469)
        at eu.henkelmann.sbt.JUnitXmlTestsListener.<init>(JUnitXmlTestListener.scala:25)
        at play.Settings$$anonfun$defaultSettings$17.apply(PlaySettings.scala:94)
        at play.Settings$$anonfun$defaultSettings$17.apply(PlaySettings.scala:94)
        at scala.Function2$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function2.scala:54)
        at scala.Function2$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function2.scala:53)
        at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
        at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
        at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
        at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
        at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
        at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
        at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
[error] (*:testListeners) java.net.UnknownHostException: linux-hkem.site: linux-hkem.site: Der Name oder der Dienst ist nicht bekannt
```

`play run` works perfectly fine in case anyone is wondering.

My `build.sbt`

```
name := "Opinions"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache
)     

play.Project.playJavaSettings
```

Those are the tests that should run:

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import org.junit.*;

import play.mvc.*;
import play.test.*;
import play.data.DynamicForm;
import play.data.validation.ValidationError;
import play.data.validation.Constraints.RequiredValidator;
import play.i18n.Lang;
import play.libs.F;
import play.libs.F.*;

import static play.test.Helpers.*;
import static org.fest.assertions.Assertions.*;

```
/**
*
* Simple (JUnit) tests that can call all parts of a play app.
* If you are interested in mocking a whole application, see the wiki for more details.
*
*/
public class ApplicationTest {

    @Test
    public void simpleCheck() {
        int a = 1 + 1;
        assertThat(a).isEqualTo(2);
    }

    @Test
    public void renderTemplate() {
        Content html = views.html.index.render("Your new application is ready.");
        assertThat(contentType(html)).isEqualTo("text/html");
        assertThat(contentAsString(html)).contains("Your new application is ready.");
    }

}
```

..

```
import org.junit.*;

import play.mvc.*;
import play.test.*;
import play.libs.F.*;

import static play.test.Helpers.*;
import static org.fest.assertions.Assertions.*;

import static org.fluentlenium.core.filter.FilterConstructor.*;

public class IntegrationTest {

    /**
     * add your integration test here
     * in this example we just check if the welcome page is being shown
     */


    @Test
    public void test() {
        running(testServer(3333, fakeApplication(inMemoryDatabase())), HTMLUNIT, new Callback<TestBrowser>() {
            public void invoke(TestBrowser browser) {
                browser.goTo("http://localhost:3333");
                assertThat(browser.pageSource()).contains("Your new application is ready.");
            }
        });
    }

}
```

..

```
package Models;

import models.*;
import org.junit.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import play.test.WithApplication;
import static play.test.Helpers.*;

public class ModelsTest extends WithApplication {

    /**
     * Start Database for testing
     */
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        start( fakeApplication(inMemoryDatabase()) );
    }

    /**
     * Create Test
     */
    @Test
    public void createAndRetrieveUser() {
        new User("jakobabfalter@gmail.com", "Apfelmann", "xxxxxx");
        User apfelmann = User.find.where().eq("email", "jakobxxxxxx@gmail.com").findUnique();
        assertNotNull(apfelmann);
        assertEquals("Apfelmann", apfelmann.getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your build file?

Comment: Can you also post your tests?

Comment: sure I can, but the program doesnt even run as far as running a test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed this editing my hosts file:

```
echo "127.0.0.1 localhost linux-hkem.site" >> /etc/hosts
```

Thanks to:

[Why does java.net.UnknownHostException require changes to the hosts file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19472124/why-does-java-net-unknownhostexception-require-changes-to-the-hosts-file)

[Play Framework GUID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8562881/play-framework-guid)