# Alternative solution to the Ehcache GUID/java.net.UnknownHostException

Tags: java, ehcache

We are running into the Ehcache GUID/java.net.UnknownHostException issue. There are known solutions to this problem answered [previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8562881/play-framework-guid). Is there any other workaround, hopefully, at the Ehcache configuration level besides editing /etc/hosts? We deploy our software to many customers and they may not have the knowledge or permissions to edit an /etc/hosts file. More broadly, it is somewhat awkward and fragile for a cache to depend on a network call or a properly configured /etc/hosts file. Can this be resolved in any other way?

Ultimately, we need a cache similar to what ehcache provides, but does not suffer from this limitation. I would prefer not to roll my own, but would entertain the possibility.

**Edit (July, 2014)**

It looks like we were running into this Java 7 bug described in the comment section [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1881967/32174). It is fixed in Java 8.

Comment: You might look for JSR-107 JCache.